# Google plus login activity with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, authentication, google-plus

Hello i have a problem to integrate the login google plus in my app. I call an Activity Login that deals with the integration with social networks. I have already integrated the code of the login of facebook and went to fruition, but when I try to integrate google plus I didn't succeed. The activity consists of a fragment and the error is here. I followed the official guidelines of google but to no avail. what can I do?

> public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements
>   NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, ConnectionCallbacks,
>   OnConnectionFailedListener {
>
> ```
> private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
>
> //google plus
> private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
> private PlusClient mPlusClient;
> private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
> private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
> private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
>
> //facebook UiLifecycleHelper
> private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
>
> //metodo callback facebook
> private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
>     @Override
>     public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) { 
>     }
> };
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
>
>     mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
>             getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
>
>     // Set up the drawer.
>     mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
>             R.id.navigation_drawer,
>             (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
>
>     //facebook login
>     uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
>     uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     //google plus
>     mPlusClient =
>           new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setActions(
>               "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
>               .setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN") // Space separated list of scopes
>               .build();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
>     // update the main content by replacing fragments
>     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
>     fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
>             .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
>             .commit();
> }
> public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
> }
>
> public void restoreActionBar() {
>     ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
>     actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
>     actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
>     actionBar.setTitle("Login/Logout");
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
>         // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
>         // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
>         // decide what to show in the action bar.
>         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
>         restoreActionBar();
>         return true;
>     }
>     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> }
> @Override
> public void onStart() {
>     super.onStart();
> }
> @Override
> public void onStop() {
>     super.onStop();
>     //facebook
>     uiHelper.onStop();
> }
> @Override
> public void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     //facebook
>     uiHelper.onResume();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onPause() {
>     super.onPause();
>     //facebook
>     uiHelper.onPause();
> }
> @Override
> public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     //facebook
>     uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>     //google plus
>     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>         mConnectionResult = null;
>         mPlusClient.connect();
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onDestroy() {
>     super.onDestroy();
>     //facebook
>     uiHelper.onDestroy();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
>     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
>     //facebook
>     uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
> }
> //********************FRAGMENT*****************************
> public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{
>
>     private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
>
>
>     public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
>         PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
>         Bundle args = new Bundle();
>         args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
>         fragment.setArguments(args);
>         return fragment;
>     }
>
>     public PlaceholderFragment() {
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       String messaggioIniziale = "E' necessario registrarsi o effettuare il login tramite Facebook.<BR><BR>";
>         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
>         TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
>         textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(messaggioIniziale));
>
>         //login button facebook
>         LoginButton buttonFacebook = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
>         buttonFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));            
>         return rootView;
>     }
> }     @Override   public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {       if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
>         // L'utente ha già fatto clic sul pulsante di accesso. Inizia a risolvere
>         // gli errori di connessione. Attendi fino a onConnected() per eliminare la
>         // finestra di dialogo di connessione.
>         if (result.hasResolution()) {
>                 try {
>                         result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
>                 } catch (SendIntentException e) {
>                         mPlusClient.connect();
>                 }
>         }
> }
> mConnectionResult = result;
>       }
> ```
>
> @Override
>   public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
>           mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();  }
>
> @Override
>   public void onDisconnected() {
>           Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");   } 
>   }

Answer (score -1):

I found two  useful answers for you, READ:

1. [Android Google plus sign in button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670656/android-google-plus-sign-in-button)
2. [Google plus sign in on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147830/google-plus-sign-in-on-android)

Good LUCK :)